# How to fix brew install issue with libffi?

Tags: homebrew, libffi

```
Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'to the 
PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

Package 'libffi', required by 'gobject-2.0', not found
```

I don't know how to fix it. Please help me out.

Comment: https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1603 ?

Comment: The relevant line for me from the link above was: `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"`

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem here under OSX by trying to install PyGObject.

I already have libffi.pc on my pc (in /usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig) and I added the PKG_CONFIG_PATH in my .bash_profile

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
```

but the installation still fails because it cannot find the file.

When it is saying to execute the command specified in https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/1603, where and when I have to do it?

Comment: `Package 'libffi' has no Name: field
Command '('pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'libffi >= 3.0')' returned non-zero exit status 1.
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygobject`